# How to parse a date that has been formatted with different locale

Tags: linux, parsing, datetime, command-line, locale

My very smart android phone has produced emails where the date field is formatted with the german locale, e.g. `Date: Di., 20 Dez. 2011 23:28:49 +0100`. I switched the phone to english to stop it doing this but a number of emails have been written already.

Some other mail program can't handle this because it doesn't have all those locales installed. As a result it set the main date-time to `Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970` and the emails appear to disappear when I sort by date :-(
So I want to fix those emails by rewriting the header. But how can I parse the german date? the `date` command supports locales on output (`date +%c`) but seems to ignore the locale on input:

```
$ date -d "08 Dec 2015"
Tue Dec  8 00:00:00 CET 2015
$ LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8 date -d "08 Dez 2015"
date: invalid date ‘08 Dez 2015’
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't do it with `date`: from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Options-for-date.html#Options-for-date): "input currently must be in locale independent format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Python and a `de` locale installed, one way would be to call

```
% python /path/to/convert.py "08 Dez 2015"
2015-12-08 00:00:00
```

where `convert.py` is this python script:

```
import sys, locale, datetime as DT
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
print(DT.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%d %b %Y'))
```